# Is there any class in Android that can be used to measure the web page load time?

Tags: android, html, load-time

I am trying to compare the web page loading time between 3G network and WiFi, so I am looking for classes that can be used in android for this purpose.

But so far I have not found any very useful class.

Has anybody done this before and what did you guys use?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you: Execute this with different network connections:

```
//start a timer here
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try 
{
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   readStream(in);
   //End timer after read stream. Log the time difference.
   finally 
   {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's also the only way I can think of so far. THX

Answer (score 0):

To compare loading times between WiFi and 3G on Android you could use WebDevTools:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voltcode.webdevtools

disclaimer - I am connected to the company that released this software.